# WIX does not remove shortcuts in the INSTALLDIR if not default

Tags: wix, shortcut, uninstallation

Why WIX does not remove a shortcut in the INSTALLDIR if it is not the default install directory is used? My WIX code look like?

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
  <Component Guid="..." Id="shortcuts_INSTALLDIR">
    <RegistryKey ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" Id="shortcuts_reg_INSTALLDIR" Key="Software\MyCompany\MyProduct" Root="HKCU">
      <RegistryValue KeyPath="yes" Name="shortcut_INSTALLDIR" Type="string" Value=""/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <Shortcut Arguments="my args " Description="my description" Id="InstallDir_my_name" Name="my name" Target="[INSTALLDIR]mydir\my.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

It look like that the uninstaller does not know the new value of INSTALLDIR. Any idea?

Comment: Do you install any files into INSTALLDIR?

Comment: No, there are only files in sub directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer is a bit of an odd beast here. It doesn't record the operations it performs; instead it tries to record the information necessary to reverse them. In this case it appears you're falling into a gap in that implementation.

Windows Installer notes that it has installed component *shortcuts_INSTALLDIR*. When a file is installed to a specific directory, it records the directory's location. Then during maintenance it restores all the directories it recorded. But it does not record (and thus does not restore) the directory for just a shortcut. Typically shortcuts are installed to predefined paths under the [ProgramMenuFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370882.aspx). Since such locations are not affected by changes to INSTALLDIR, this is usually not a problem.

To solve this you have to ensure the alternate INSTALLDIR is restored during maintenance. You can convince Windows Installer to do so automatically by installing any file directly to INSTALLDIR (if the extra file is not a problem, this is my preferred option). Alternately you can do so manually through the remember property pattern, possibly leveraging [ARPINSTALLLOCATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367589.aspx) and its saved value in the Uninstall key.